# Entity Framework Migrations: Why string property ignores IsRequired"?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Here's my POCO

```
public class Game
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Galaxy> Galaxies { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the TypeConfiguration ....

```
public class GameConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Game>
{
    public GameConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasMany(x => x.Galaxies);

        Property(x => x.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

My question is this... why, when this is added as a migration does the migration code not set the "Name" property as a "NOT NULL"?  It also ignores the MaxLength setting too.  Why is this?

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Games",
    c => new
    {
        Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
        Name = c.String(),
    })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Comment: This might be too obvious but are you certain that the entity configuration is being registered in the model builder? At first glance the rest of your configuration matches what would happen by convention even if the configuration constructor never ran and the if the name property is missing that could explain it.

Comment: Now I feel really dumb.  you are correct, the entity configuration was not being registered in the context's constructor.  Can you post that as an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Comment: Ok. Don't feel dumb! :) Glad it helped.

Comment: I feel dumb because I use this all the time and already know about registering the type configuration in OnModelCreating... I spent hours looking for a problem caused by my own oversight.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance the rest of your configuration matches what would happen by convention even if the configuration constructor never ran and the if the name property is missing that could explain it. The code that registers the configuration in the model builder is missing.

You can register the entity configuration, e.g. inside the OnModelCreated method like this:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GameConfiguration());
```